# What is the etymology of this child's melody about stepping on kittens?

Tags: etymology, song-lyrics

I came across an insane child's melody about stepping kittens. What is the etymology of this melody?

[猫ふんじゃった](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3y5JrNclaDM)

And, what does "かつぶしゃる" mean?

Comment: After looking at the link, I believe there is a typo; it should be かつぶしやる instead of かつぶしゃる.

Comment: This makes me think about an insanely cruel song from my childhood about a family of small rabbits who went out for a walk and for a reason or another they all started dying: one shot by a hunter, one drowning and so on up to the last one who, alone, died of a broken heart. I really wonder who comes up with such lyrics for kids songs.. and why somehow they get to the kids I mean.. someone has to sing them. lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not かつぶしゃる but かつぶし + やる. かつぶし is [かつおぶし](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katsuobushi) (known in Japan as cats' favorite food), and やる is "to give". "猫かつぶしやるからよっといで" = "Cat, I'll give you katsuobushi, so come closer."

---

The melody itself is [Flea Waltz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Der_Flohwalzer), and is known all over the world under various names. The composer is unknown.

The best-known Japanese lyrics, which you linked, were written by Hiroo Sakata in the 1960's. There is [another version by Toshio Oka](https://mojim.com/jpy112799x1x19.htm). The English lyrics you posted look somewhat similar to Sakata's version, but looks much more cruel and weird. Where did you find it?

There are a few people who study this song (like [Rumiko Miyamoto](http://www.geocities.co.jp/MusicHall/2623/)), but apparently no one knows why the lyricist came up with these lines. But are they that insane? I mean, as compared to Mother Goose, for example?

Comment: ha. ha. Where did I find it?... Well, I was killing time and watching "World's Weirdest Toys" on youtube. There was a toy that looked like a cat run-over by a car. The title was "ねこふんじゃった." I googled that title and saw that the toy was based on an 絵本. What I linked to is an animated version of that 絵本. My niece loves cats, so idea of stomping on cats was startling to me.

Comment: In my search, I did find かつぶし as a type of fish, but that didn't fit the version of the song I was using. Your answer is so interesting. I need to do more thinking about this tomorrow. thanks!

Comment: @riverflows ～じゃった (=[てしまった](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21026/5010)) expresses that it was accidental and regrettable. Sakata's version basically says "I accidentally stepped on you, sorry!" Maybe someone who is not good at Japanese did this cruel translation...?

Comment: Bonito flake = Katsuobushi

Comment: There's also a version with こねこふんじゃった "I (accidentally) stepped on a *kitten*". The rhythm is just a little different: https://youtu.be/3UHiyFzobGc