# What does どうなちきつたんだよオ mean?

Tags: grammar, meaning, particles, readings, manga

I am trying to learn a lot by reading, but I am having a lot of trouble with this phrase/sentence:

> どうなちきつたんだよオ

Now, this is from a manga (Akira, specifically) so I'm guessing it's some kind of cheesy/loud exclamation. But I've tried to figure out what it means and I'm just really not getting it.

This is the the original image.

[image]
*<sup>(Click for full image.)</sup>*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not どうなちきつたんだよオ but どうな**っちま**ったんだよ**ォ**, which in this context roughly means "What happened to you!" or "What has become of you!" I don't know how much you know about Japanese, but assuming you can read most of what's written in AKIRA, here's the breakdown. (If you still have trouble reading hiragana, you should start with something easier.)

- どう: "how"
- なっちまった: contracted form of なってしまった (see [this chart](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18159/5010))

  - なって: te-form of なる ("to become", "to turn out")
  - しまった: ta-form of しまう ("to end up"; see [「しまう」 as an auxiliary verb](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21026/5010))
- ん: explanatory-no; see [What is the meaning of ～んです/～のだ/etc?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5398/5010)
- だ: copula
- よォ: the same as よ, a masculine sentence-end particle

(どうなる is a set phrase meaning "what happens", "how it's going")