# What is the difference between してしまいそう and しそうだ

Tags: grammar, jlpt, shinkanzen-master

I've come across this sentence in Shinkanzen Master N3 Reading, and I don't understand what the difference is.
The sentence goes as follows:
遅刻してしまいそうだ。it then asks what the difference would be, if the sentence were 遅刻しそうだ。
I would greatly appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Fabio, and welcome! Have you encountered the construction ~てしまう before? If so, this has been answered previously: check out [「しまう」 as an auxiliary verb](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21026/%e3%81%97%e3%81%be%e3%81%86-as-an-auxiliary-verb)