# Why is ちゃう used without negative connotation in the following sentence?

Tags: て-form, sentence

> 俺って誰かさんと違うえらい子だから。Because I am admirable, unlike a certain someone.
>
> 空気読んじゃうんだよね。[I] surely can read the mood.

So the POV character is watching two friends flirt and he's pretending to be asleep. When one of them says "I can read the mood", I don't see why he'd use 読んじゃう over 読める for example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [「しまう」 as an auxiliary verb](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21026/%e3%81%97%e3%81%be%e3%81%86-as-an-auxiliary-verb)

Comment: Any chance it's the "do completely" -ちゃう (しまう)?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a sense of doing something without even trying/meaning/thinking. 空気読める is kind of neutral in this regard.

> 空気読んじゃうんだよね 
> It's because (without even trying) I end up reading the mood, y'know?

It could also have a negative connotation like "(I don't even want to but / regrettably) I end up reading the mood" which doesn't seem to be the case given the previous clause.

---

Grammatically

読んじゃう -> 読んで + しまう