N3 Sample Test Question
A questions from an old JLPT test reads
乗っている電車が急に止まって、隣に立っていた人に新しい白い靴を（）
The two options I was debating between were
a. 踏んでしまった
and
b. 踏まれてしまった
Why is the answer B and not A?

This question is testing your understanding of active versus passive voice.

踏んだ stepped on (active)
踏まれた being stepped on (passive)

I will omit "しまった" for now, as it's not necessary to distinguish between active and passive voice. Let's start with a simple example.

人は私の靴を踏んだ (active): A person stepped on my shoe.
私は靴を人に踏まれた (passive): I had my shoe stepped on by a person.

Notice that particle "に" in the passive sentence. The noun before "に" indicates who performs the action, similar to "by" in English.
Now, let's return to your question:
『隣に立っていた人』に『新しい白い靴』を（）
The "に" in this sentence shows that it is the passive voice. Therefore, the correct answer should be "b. 踏まれてしまった."
Though it's not crucial for solving this question, I'll explain the nuance of てしまった. When a sentence ends with てしまった, it adds a sense of regret or negativity about what happened.

踏まれた: was stepped on (just telling the fact )
踏まれてしまった: was stepped on (with the nuance that it was an unfortunate or regrettable outcome)


For てしまった, ref. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21026.
